# Mutable internal value in discriminated union

Tags: f#, mutable, discriminated-union

The task is to create a binary tree with its nodes having a member `is_locked` that can be true or false and a method `lock()` that shall set `is_locked` to true if it's not already.

I tried this

```ml
type BinaryTreeNode =
    | Node of BinaryTreeNode * BinaryTreeNode
    | End
    with
        let mutable internalIsLocked = false
        member this.is_locked
            with get() = internalIsLocked 
        member this.lock() = internalIsLocked <- true
```

but compiler says no due to `This declaration element is not permitted in an augmentation` at the let binding.

`val mutable internalIsLocked : bool` instead does not work for the same reason.

How can this problem be solved then?
Is it not solvable with discriminated unions?

Comment: You can't have state on an ADT. Use a regular class instead. Or, better yet, don't use mutable state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you can move the mutable state into a separate class type, and then use that type in your discriminated union:

```ml
type Lock() =
    let mutable internalIsLocked = false
    member this.is_locked
        with get() = internalIsLocked 
    member this.lock() = internalIsLocked <- true

type BinaryTreeNode =
    | Node of Lock * BinaryTreeNode * BinaryTreeNode
    | End
    with
    static member Create(left, right) =
        Node (Lock(), left, right)
    member this.Lock =
        match this with
            | Node (lock, _, _) -> Some lock
            | End -> None
```

Note that I've assumed that `End` nodes are not lockable. Usage:

```ml
let node = BinaryTreeNode.Create(End, End)
node.Lock.Value.is_locked |> printfn "%A"   // false
node.Lock.Value.lock()
node.Lock.Value.is_locked |> printfn "%A"   // true
```

However, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would you instead recommend? A normal class?

Comment: It depends on why you need to lock the nodes. In general, I prefer immutable data structures.

Comment: I should add that the task is from a coding interview I wanted to solve. I also try to avoid mutability if possible.